# Spring Boot 2.x multiple datasource and jdbctemplate

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I would like to use Multiple Datasources and JdbcTemplates in my Spring Boot 2.1.3 Application.

I tried all solution advices on Stackoverflow and other web sites. But in my application;
when I try to create a Jdbctemplate instance with specified datasource, it sets null for datasources.

I couldn't understand where the problem is? Hikari Pool starts after application ready event. How to set a datasource of jdbcTemplate after initializations of datasources ?

Here is my code examples:

```
@Bean(name = "iybsDS")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.iybs")
public DataSource iybsDSdataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "diyihDS")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.diyih")
public DataSource diyihDSdataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

JdbcTemplate Config:

```
@Configuration
public class JdbcTemplateConfig {

@Bean(name = "diyihJdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate CreateDiyihJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("diyihDS") DataSource diyihDS) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(diyihDS);
   }
}
```

Trying for print datasource information on console:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebservicesApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("diyihDS")
DataSource diyihDS;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebservicesApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(diyihDS);
   }
}
```

Output is :

```
2019-03-07 14:27:20.026  INFO 20100 --- [           main] t.g.a.WebservicesApplication             : Started WebservicesApplication in 4.724 seconds (JVM running for 5.594)
HikariDataSource (null)
...
2019-03-07 14:27:20.739  INFO 20100 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : DiyihPool - Starting...
2019-03-07 14:27:20.817  INFO 20100 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : DiyihPool - Start completed.
```

When I tried to send a request to web service in my application, I got error because datasource of JdbcTemplate is wrong or null.

**I GOT MY MISTAKE:** 
I was trying just one JdbcTemplate instance. I created all needed jdbcTemplates and set a Primary one of them. Then each service had own JdbcTemplate and Datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DataSourceProperties` Bean and use it:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.diyih") 
public DataSourceProperties diyihDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name="diyihDS")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.diyih")
public DataSource diyihDataSource() {
    return diyihDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
```

Comment: What should I add under "spring.datasource.diyih" to application.properties?

Comment: @MevlütSungur url, user and password